# Trouble closing CamelContext in Cucumber test

Tags: java, apache-camel, cucumber

**The problem**

The problem is somewhat small but as follows:
When having multiple scenario's in a Cucumber test, the log is polluted with the following message:

```
14:54:54.021 [Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - TemporaryQueueReplyManager[queueName]] ERROR o.a.c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'temporary' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=26, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: null
```

**What am I doing**

So I've got an application which produces a fat-jar. In my Cucumber test I run this jar for each scenario from its own working directory. The jar uses JMS, so I create an ActiveMQ broker in the test to do the communicating. While the jar is not using Apache-Camel, the Cucumber tests do use Camel.

At the start of each Scenario, the jar is installed, Camel context is built, AMQ broker is started and lastly the jar is started.

Then the test steps occur, both using Routes in case the jar has the initiative and using a producer in case the application I'm stubbing has the initiative.

At the end of the test I first stop the application, call stop on the CamelContext and stop the broker.

The pattern seems to be that for each Scenario in the same feature file, which is under the same JUnit run definition, the number of occurrences of the above shown error seems to increase.

My hypothesis is that something in the CamelContext is lingering which causes the message.

**What I've tried**

At the start of the project, Camel version 2.19.5 was selected. I've tried running it with version 2.24.3 which did not change anything.

The rest of my attempts are in this block where I stop the CamelContext and the broker:

```
    camelContext.getShutdownStrategy().setSuppressLoggingOnTimeout(true);
    camelContext.getShutdownStrategy().setLogInflightExchangesOnTimeout(false);
    camelContext.getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
    camelContext.stop();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        Awaitility.await().atMost(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).until(() -> camelContext.getRoutes().isEmpty());
    } finally {
        LOG.info("Waited time for Camel was {}", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (broker != null) {
            broker.getBrokerService().stop();
            broker.getBrokerService().waitUntilStopped();
            LOG.info("Waited time for ActiveMQ was {}", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        }
    }
```

The resulting logging was around 100ms for Camel and under 10ms for ActiveMQ.